# Entitiy Framework: Defining relations with Code First Approach

Tags: database-design, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, code-first

As a newbie to Entity Framework and its approaches, I have a couple of model classes which i want to use them for creating database tables with code first approach. The id of  `User`model refers to 2 tables and points atleast 2 columns for each of these tables as shown below.

```
    public class ControlGroup
    {

        public int ControlGroupId { get; set; }

        public string ControlGroupName { get; set; }

        public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

        public virtual User UpdatedBy { get; set; }

        public DateTime UpdateTime { get; set; }

    }

    public class ControlPoint
    {

        public int ControlPointId { get; set; }

        public string ControlPointName { get; set; }

        public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

        public virtual User UpdatedBy { get; set; }

        public virtual User Auditor{ get; set; }

        public DateTime UpdateTime { get; set; }

    }

    public class User
    {

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public string UserFirstName { get; set; }

        public string UserLastName { get; set; }

        public string UserPassword { get; set; }

        public string UserEmail { get; set; }

        public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; }

    }
```

I have already defined `User` in `ControlGroup` and and `ControlPoint` classes but i am confused about how to define the relationship in `User` class. Do i need to put 5 attiributes in `User` for each of `User` object in other two classes or just one is enough ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add to all of your classes ID field
2. Add navigation properties to User class
3. I assume that you have one-to-many relationship between User and ControlPoint, ControlGroup entities.
4. I deleted field UserType from User, because you have not shown UserType class declaration and not specified relationship between them (I dont know what to do with it, solve it on your own).

At the end models will look like this:

```
public class ControlGroup
{
    //was added
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int ControlGroupId { get; set; }    
    public string ControlGroupName { get; set; }    
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }    
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }    
    public virtual User UpdatedBy { get; set; }    
    public DateTime UpdateTime { get; set; }    
}

public class ControlPoint
{
    //was added
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int ControlPointId { get; set; }    
    public string ControlPointName { get; set; }    
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }    
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }    
    public virtual User UpdatedBy { get; set; }    
    public virtual User Auditor { get; set; }    
    public DateTime UpdateTime { get; set; }    
}

public class User
{
    //was added
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }    
    public string UserFirstName { get; set; }    
    public string UserLastName { get; set; }    
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }    
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }

    //on your own
    //public virtual UserType UserType { get; set; }

    //navigation properties one-to-many were added
    [InverseProperty("Auditor")]
    public virtual ICollection<ControlPoint> ControlPointAuditor { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("UpdatedBy")]
    public virtual ICollection<ControlPoint> ControlPointUpdatedBy { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("CreatedBy")]
    public virtual ICollection<ControlPoint> ControlPointCreatedBy { get; set; }    
    [InverseProperty("UpdatedBy")]
    public virtual ICollection<ControlGroup> ControlGroupUpdatedBy { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("CreatedBy")]
    public virtual ICollection<ControlGroup> ControlGroupCreatedBy { get; set; }
    //navigation one-to-many
}
```